# Linux service install on Amazon linux bootstrap

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**TLDR**: How to install/configure/start Linux services (like apache httpd) with the help of bootstrap script those are included as part of EC2 instance User Data.

**Background**: I am in process of setting up a confluent eco system (confluent schema registry and rest proxy) in an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux ami-0a13d44dccf1f5cf6).
Once EC2 comes active, I SSH into instance and download packages, make config changes and then run these applications (schema registry and rest proxy) in separate shell command (via Putty). This is fine and working as I expected. This is not scalable since it involve manual steps (downloading package/ modifying config/starting applications).

**Solution**: The solution I have in mind is to write bootstrap script within UserData for the EC2 instance. This would help me to replace all manual activities. So the bootstrap (please see below), at high level contains steps to download package, modify some config file and create 2 services in Linux to run applications (schema registry and rest proxy).

**Question**: I was able to setup the solution. However, my services are not created/initialized/started. Can you point me on where I am going wrong or any advise ?

*Note: I am a Linux newbie; and using `systemctl` to check existence of service and I couldn't locate the .service file in `.../systemd/system`.*

**Update:** When I try to use following command to see the unit file definition, I am getting messages such as *'Unit xxx is not loaded: No such file or directory'*

```
systemctl cat confluent-schema-registry.service
```

*Unit confluent-schema-registry.service is not loaded: No such file or directory*

```
systemctl cat confluent-kafka-rest.service
```

*Unit confluent-kafka-rest.service is not loaded: No such file or directory*

```
UserData: !Base64 >
 #!/bin/bash
 
 yum update -y
 yum install -y httpd
 systemctl start httpd
 systemctl enable httpd
 
 yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel -y
 cd /home/ec2-user
 echo "export PATH=.local/bin:$PATH" >> .bash_profile
 mkdir kafka
 
 cd kafka
 wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.4.1/kafka_2.12-2.4.1.tgz
 tar -xzf kafka_2.12-2.4.1.tgz
 rm -rf kafka_2.12-2.4.1.tgz
 
 wget http://packages.confluent.io/archive/5.4/confluent-community-5.4.1-2.12.tar.gz
 tar -xzf confluent-community-5.4.1-2.12.tar.gz
 rm -rf confluent-community-5.4.1-2.12.tar.gz
 
 chown -R ec2-user ./kafka
 chgrp -R ec2-user ./kafka
 
 cd /home/ec2-user/kafka
 mkdir log
 cd log
 chown -R ec2-user ./log
 chgrp -R ec2-user ./log
 
 sudo -i

 #Kafka Schema Registry
 sed -i 's|old|new|g' /home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties           

 #REST PROXY
 sed -i 's|old|new|g' /home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties

 sudo -i
 
 #Setup unit in systemd for Schema Registry
 echo -n "
 [Unit]
 Description=Confluent Schema Registry
 After=network.target

 [Service]
 Type=simple
 User=ec2-user
 Environment="LOG_DIR=/home/ec2-user/kafka/log/schema-registry"
 ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/bin/schema-registry-start /home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
 ExecStop=/home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/bin/schema-registry-stop
 Restart=on-abnormal

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target" > /etc/systemd/system/confluent-schema-registry.service

 #Setup unit in systemd for REST Proxy
 echo -n "
 [Unit]
 Description=Confluent Rest Proxy
 After=network.target

 [Service]
 Type=simple
 User=ec2-user
 Environment="LOG_DIR=/home/ec2-user/kafka/log/kafka-rest"
 ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/bin/kafka-rest-start /home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties
 ExecStop=/home/ec2-user/kafka/confluent-5.4.1/bin/kafka-rest-stop
 Restart=on-abnormal

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target" > /etc/systemd/system/confluent-kafka-rest.service
 

 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 
 sudo systemctl enable confluent-schema-registry.service

 sudo systemctl start confluent-schema-registry.service
 
 sudo systemctl enable confluent-kafka-rest.service

 sudo systemctl start confluent-kafka-rest.service
```